# Is collapse clause with non-rectangular loops allowed by the OpenMP 5.1 Spec?

Tags: multithreading, loops, parallel-processing, openmp

Consider the following OpenMP code:

```
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for collapse(4) map(tofrom: a) private(i,j,k,l)
for (i = 0; i < SIZE_N; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < SIZE_M; j++) {
    for (k = i; k < SIZE_N; k++) {
       for (l = 0; l < SIZE_M; l++) {
         a[i][j][k][l] += i+2*j+3*k+4*l;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Is this code OpenMP Spec 5.1 compliant? I could not find in the spec any wording that does not allowed this kind of code, but I am not sure I am missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this OpenMP Spec 5.1 compliant?

Accordingly to [Support for non-rectangular collapsed loops](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/05/03/new-features-in-openmp-5-0-and-5-1#) yes it is compliant.

> **Before OpenMP 5.0**, all OpenMP looping constructs (worksharing loops,
> simd, distribute, taskloop, and combined or composite constructs based
> on those) **were required to be rectangular.** This means that all of the
> lower bound, upper bound, and increment expressions of all the
> associated loops in the loop nest were required to be invariant
> against the outermost loop. **OpenMP 5.0** still requires all the
> increment expressions to be loop-invariant, but **allows some cases
> where the lower and upper bound expressions of the inner loops can be
> based on a single outer-loop iterator.**

> I cannot find in the spec any
> wording that does not allowed this kind of code, but I am not sure I am missing something.

In the [OpenMP 5.0 specification](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5.0.pdf) page 625, *Version 4.5 to 5.0 Differences*, one can read the following:

> The collapse of associated loops that are imperfectly nested loops
> was defined for the worksharing-loop (see Section 2.9.2 on page 101),
> simd (see Section 2.9.3.1 on page 110), taskloop (see Section 2.10.2
> on page 140) and distribute (see Section 2.9.4.2 on page 123)
> constructs.

Comment: I would like to add that while the OpenMP API v5.1 has now well-defined behavior for non-rectangular loops for collapse, it may be that your OpenMP implementation does not yet support this.  Please check with the compiler change log, if they already have support for this.