# omp parallel for slower for a more straightforward movement through a container?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to parallelize the following:

```
int l_max = 16;
int contor = 0;

for (int l=0; l<l_max; l++) {
    for (int m=-l; m<(l+1); m++) {
    // Here do some linear algebra whose "logic" depends on both l and m.
    // Each such work is totally independent from the other works for other (l,m) pairs.
    // Everything is embarrassingly parallel.
    // At the end of each of the double-for-loop's iteration, store the "result" in a container. 
    // The container can be anything which can store objects of the type xt::xarray<std::complex<double>>.
    // I chose a std::array< xt::xarray<std::complex<double>>, l_max*l_max >, which I initialized above the for (int l=0; l<l_max; l++) instruction.
    container[contor] = result_for_this_l_m_pair_work;
    contor += 1;
    }
}
```

I went through introductory tutorials for OpenMP and I can now get speedup using:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
for (int l=0; i<l_max; l++) {
    int contor;
        for (int m=-l; m<(l+1); m++) {
            contor = l*l + (m+l);
            // Here do some linear algebra whose "logic" depends on both l and m.
            container[contor] = result_for_this_l_m_pair_work;
        }
}
```

I then thought: wait a minute, this double for-in-for loop can be translated to just one for-loop by iterating through pairs (l,m) from a pre-defined and populated 1D array (or vector). The 1D array shall look like (in pseudocode): `l_m_s_container = [(0,0), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, -2), (2, -1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), ... etc]`. I populated such an array and I now have:

```
 int l_max_squared = l_max * l_max;
 #pragma omp parallel for // tried both: schedule(dynamic) and schedule(static)
 for (int i=0; i<l_max_squared; i++) {
     int l = l_m_s_container[i].first;
     int m = l_m_s_container[i].second;
     int contor = l * l + (l + m);
     // Here do some linear algebra whose "logic" depends on both l and m.
     container[contor] = result_for_this_l_m_pair_work;
 }
```

I obtain SLOWER time-to-solution (i.e. all the work being completely done) using my "fancier" second approach.
The first approach yields a time-to-solution of ~ 420 ms.
The second approach is slower by > 100 ms.
The input parameters I used are: `l_max = 16` and I use 16 threads (the default given by OpenMP).

Do you know what is happening and if there is another way to improve the efficiency of the code more?

At the moment, this strange for-in-for-loop is the bottleneck in my code. It takes ~400 ms and I need to run this logic twice per timestep. One timestep takes in total ~1000 ms. Thus if I manage to get this for-in-for loop to < 400 ms, it would greatly improve everything.

Thank you!

Comment: Cache locality check: the fancy container might be a continuous container, in which case you're loading the same cache line to all cores.

Comment: Thank you both. The typo is indeed a typo, now corrected. ``l_max_squared`` is defined in main() as `l_max_squared` = `l_max * l_max`, now edited.

Comment: There is a load imbalance in your first loop as you have just 16 iterations. All threads have to wait until the slowest thread finishes. To speed it you have to reduce the imbalance by increasing the number of chunks: move `int cotor` to the second loop and use collapse(2) clause. Also try to reverse the order of the first loop, use `collapse(2)` and `schedule(guided)` clauses. It helps to minimize the load imbalance.

Comment: How fast is the serial code (compared to 420 vs 520 ms)? How container is defined?

Comment: Since `l_max` is small (16) and so the number of iteration (`l_max_squared` is 256), the provided code is very likely not the source of the overhead (at least, not directly). If each parallel loop takes 400 ms, then nearly all the time should be spent in `Here do some linear algebra whose "logic" depends on both l and m`. Something tell me that all the performance issues comes from that. It might be due to NUMA effects regarding the target machine. Details matters in high-performance, unfortunately they are not provided (ie target platform and exact code, including the initialization).

Comment: By the way, if the 400 ms are for the overall execution time and there is a lot of timestep, then the problem is the overhead to (create thread and) share the work between thread that could be the problem. It takes some time to communicate between cores (and OpenMP adds some overheads). Not to mention the memory access will likely not take the same time on different cores (due to many complex low-level effects). Parallel loops should generally take >100 us so for the overheads to be small.

Comment: @velenos14 Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Sorry for my delay and thanks for trying to help, I had some issues / problems. @Laci, the code inside the commented region uses ``xtensor`` https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor which depends on ``blas`` (for example, OpenBLAS https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS). I do not use plain C++ or C. Would you be able to "install" xtensor on your computer? Or is there other way me to produce a MWE?

Comment: @JérômeRichard, one complete movement through all the ``l_max_squared = 256`` iterations of the ``// Here do some linear algebra whose "logic" depends on both l and m //`` takes roughly 400 ms, when parallelized as in my second code written in my question (i.e. the naive ``#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)``). So the "parallel" loop takes more than 100 microseconds indeed. Did I understand your comment right?

Comment: @Laci, the serial approach (for in for loop, no OpenMP involved at all) takes roughly 800 ms (sometimes 790 ms, sometimes 813 ms, I really don't know why it differs between them), whereas the naive ``#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)`` approach takes roughly 400 ms

Comment: OpenBLAS also uses threads, it can be set it by e.g. `export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4`. So, in your case how many threads are used? You run a calculation depending on complex libraries and most of the time is spent there. So, you may try to chanage their settings (like number of threads used)

Comment: @Laci, I didn't touch anything related to OpenBLAS' number of threads up until now. I just installed ``xtensor`` and its ``xtensor-blas`` extension, as in here: https://xtensor-blas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html, after having installed OpenBLAS with ``sudo apt-get install ...``.  The only thing I was controlling is the OpenMP number of threads and I was by default given 16 threads by OpenMP. I have now tried to set ``export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=`` to 1, 2, 4. Timings are best for 1 thread and are as 320-350-380 ms, getting worse as the number in OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS increases

Comment: If I understand well, instead of 400 ms it takes 320 ms uisng `export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1` ? If so, the good news is that you got 20% increase in speed, the bad news is that you have already used a parallel library, so you cannot expect a big speed-up... What about the second code?

Comment: @Laci, would you please be able to detail a bit on the collapse clause you mentioned? From what I am reading, I cannot do it because it's not a rectangular loop: the inner loop iterations depend on the current outer loop iteration count ``l`` (because of the ``for (int m=-l; m<(l+1); m++) {...}``

Comment: @velenos14 OpenMP 5.0 can handle [non-rectangular loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68382400/is-collapse-clause-with-non-rectangular-loops-allowed-by-the-openmp-5-1-spec)

Comment: @Laci, hmmm, thank you! I need to go to the HPC machine then as my computer does not support such advanced gcc's inside a WSL with Ubuntu 20.04 ...

Comment: @lorro, can that problem be solved with a reduction or do I need to use padding (which is to be avoided if I am not wrong?)